# Replace _ to / while update value on PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Here the list of my value of table : tree

•   TREE_2ED
•   TREE_2ED_CIN
•   TREE_2ED_EM
•   TREE_2ED_ENV
•   TREE_2ED_SRF
•   TREE_DA
•   TREE_DA_CID
•   TREE_DA_DSR
•   TREE_DA_EM
•   TREE_DA_EST
•   TREE_DA_REP
•   TREE_DAC
•   TREE_DAC_EM
•   TREE1_DAC_EM
•   TREE2_DAC_EM

**What I want :**

While updating value replace all my value who begin with "TREE%" replace the "_" to "/".

**Example :**

•   initial value : TREE_2ED

- updated value : TREE / 2ED

**What I have done :**

```
UPDATE tree
    SET value = (CASE WHEN value LIKE 'TREE%'
                     THEN ''
                END)
```

Is it possible to do this operation with pgsql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function:

```sql
UPDATE tree
SET    value = REPLACE(value, '_', '/')
WHERE  value LIKE 'TREE%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a filtered update:

```
UPDATE tree
    SET value = REPLACE(value, '_', '/')
    WHERE value LIKE 'TREE%';
```